# Acoustic resonance inside an enclosed sphere

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance

I apologize if this question is too basic.

Assume an acoustic source suspended at the center of a hollow spherical shell. (The reason why the central acoustic source is suspended inside the sphere can be whatever's most helpful: a zero-G environment; electromagnetic levitation; or anything else.)

Other than the solid acoustic source, the shell is otherwise filled with air at standard ambient temperature and pressure. The size and shape of the acoustic source, its density, the radius of the enclosing spherical shell, its thickness, density, and other properties, and the frequencies and amplitudes of the sounds produced, are up for grabs.

Crucially, the sphere does not have a hole or "neck" or similar topological features.

Under approximately what conditions/values would the sound(s) produced by the central acoustic source cause resonance in the spherical shell? Ideally, resonance that would lead to visible vibration of the shell but not breakage.

This isn't Helmholtz resonance because the sphere isn't vented.

Any insights appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a clear answer to this. The obvious resonance comes from the round-trip time for the wave to expand, and bounce back, and be focused onto the source.  But the problem is, it all depends on what happens at the focus:  Does the source get in the way (yes)? How well focused is the acoustic wave? Does the system stay linear? Etc. These details of the focal point can be very important, as in, say, a [sonoluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence) setup, where, in liquids, the focusing of the acoustic wave leads to highly nonlinear effects (eg, 20,000K flashes, etc).

Comment: If all you are looking for is the ability to visually measure the sound on the outside, this is easily done with any source as long as your shell is sufficiently thin.  Any acoustic wave will cause motion, and you can pick that up using, e.g., a laser doppler vibrometer (LDV) system.  Why does it need to be at some sort of resonance?